# Геокодер Яндекса и карта в выпадающем блоке

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

У яндекса в правилах использования бесплатного API есть пункт: "Данные, полученные средствами API, должны быть показаны на карте Яндекса".

А если карта на сайте по умолчанию скрыта и показывается при клике на кнопку "показать карту", не будет ли это нарушением правил?

Все запросы к геокодеру на карте показаны.

Answer (score 0):

Как правило Яндекс допускает размещение карты в сворачиваемом блоке, если ссылка/кнопка для показа карты названа и расположена очевидным образом.

Но в целом спорные вопросы по соблюдению [условий использования](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/) лучше задавать именно в их поддержку — всегда можно будет апеллировать к официальному ответу в переписке, в случае возможных претензий по соблюдению этих самых правил.